# Running python loops / numpy operations on GPU

Tags: python, numpy

Is it possible to run regular python loops which involves numpy on GPU? say, I have the following code:

```
def data_preprocess(data_dir, seq_length):
data = open(data_dir, 'r', encoding="utf8").read()
chars = sorted(list(set(data)))
VOCAB_SIZE = len(chars)

print('Data length: {} characters'.format(len(data)))
print('Vocabulary size: {} characters'.format(VOCAB_SIZE))

ix_to_char = {ix: char for ix, char in enumerate(chars)}
char_to_ix = {char: ix for ix, char in enumerate(chars)}

X = np.zeros((len(data) // seq_length, seq_length, VOCAB_SIZE))
y = np.zeros((len(data) // seq_length, seq_length, VOCAB_SIZE))
for i in range(0, len(data) // seq_length):
    X_sequence = data[i * seq_length:(i + 1) * seq_length]
    X_sequence_ix = [char_to_ix[value] for value in X_sequence]
    input_sequence = np.zeros((seq_length, VOCAB_SIZE))
    for j in range(seq_length):
        input_sequence[j][X_sequence_ix[j]] = 1.
        X[i] = input_sequence

    y_sequence = data[i * seq_length + 1:(i + 1) * seq_length + 1]
    y_sequence_ix = [char_to_ix[value] for value in y_sequence]
    target_sequence = np.zeros((seq_length, VOCAB_SIZE))
    for j in range(seq_length):
        target_sequence[j][y_sequence_ix[j]] = 1.
        y[i] = target_sequence
return X, y, VOCAB_SIZE, ix_to_char
```

Data length is 18863769

Vocabulary size is 394

`seq_length` is 30

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no, Python doesn't run on GPUs.

Longer answer: I'm guessing you don't want to use the GPU per se, you just want this to run faster. Some ideas:

- You might be able to gain some speed by avoiding `for` loops in favour of numpy's own vectorization.
- Try pypy, which is a drop-in replacement for the standard Python interpeter that is often 5-10x faster, depending on workload.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/), its specifically geared towards running numpy-centric programs on cuda-enabled gpus. there are also a lot of examples on the [github page](https://github.com/numba/numba/tree/master/examples) for better understanding.

if you have an nvidia cuda-enabled gpu, here's a quick [how-to guide](https://developer.nvidia.com/how-to-cuda-python)

hope this helps.